# The new object the user created doesn't add to the list and neither does it shows at the scene

Tags: java, list, javafx, arraylist

I have problems adding my new object `Causa` to the List where these objects save.

Basically, my program needs to allow the user to add a new cause and save it to the List where these objects are for then, show it in the scene. My main controller is something like this:

```
public class VistaPrincipalController implements Initializable {

    private ArrayList<Causa> causa = (ArrayList<Causa>) Causa.leerCausas(); 
    private ArrayList<Causa> causas = new ArrayList<>(causa);

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        for(Causa c : causas){
            VBox vboxcausa = new VBox();
            ImageView imgview = null;
            try{
                //Add image
                InputStream input = App.class.getResource(c.getImagen()).openStream();
                Image img = new Image(input, 100,100, true, true);
                imgview = new ImageView(img);
            }catch(NullPointerException | IOException ex){
                //If image not found
                imgview = new ImageView();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So for each 'Causa', it should give me a new VBox with the information of the cause

The class `Causa` is like this:

```
public class Causa {
    private String nombre;
    private String descripcion;
    //Name of the image
    private String imagen;
    private double meta;

    public Causa(String nombre, String imagen,
        String descripcion, double meta){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.imagen = imagen;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.meta = meta;
    }

    public static List<Causa> leerCausas(){

    List<Causa> causa = Arrays.asList(
    
        new Causa("Operation 1",
                "causa1.png",
                "Description 1",
                1000),
        new Causa("Operation 2 ",
                "causa2.png",
                "Description 2));

        ArrayList<Causa> causas = new ArrayList<>(causa);
        return causas;
}
```

Then I have my class `Fundacion`:

```
public class Fundacion {
    List<Causa> causas;

    public Fundacion(){
        causas = Causa.leerCausas();
    }

    public void guardarCausa(Causa nuevaCausa){
        causas.add(nuevaCausa);
    }
}
```

Then I have my secondary controller `NuevaCausaController` which is something like this:

```
public class NuevaCausaController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<Integer> cbMeta;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtNombre;
    @FXML
    private TextField txtImagen;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtDescripcion;

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        ArrayList<Integer> opciones = new ArrayList<>();
        opciones.add(100);
        opciones.add(200);
        opciones.add(500);
        opciones.add(1000);
    
        cbMeta.getItems().addAll(opciones);
        // ALL
    }    

    @FXML
    private void addCausa(ActionEvent event){
        String nombre = txtNombre.getText();
        String imagen = txtImagen.getText();
        String descripcion = txtDescripcion.getText();
        Double meta = Double.valueOf(cbMeta.getValue());
    
        if(!nombre.isBlank()){
        
            Causa nuevaCausa = new Causa(nombre, imagen, descripcion, meta);
            App.getFundacion().guardarCausa(nuevaCausa);
            
            try{
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource("VistaPrincipal.fxml"));
                Parent viewPrincipal = loader.load();
                App.setRoot(viewPrincipal);
                    
                }catch(IOException ex){                       
                    System.out.println("Error loading view");
                    System.out.println("VistaPrincipal.fxml");
                }
           
            
        
        
        }else{
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setContentText("Error");
            alert.setHeaderText("Error");
            alert.showAndWait();   

        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesn't add this new object to the list, so neither it appears in the first scene where it should appear all the saved 'Causas'.

Comment: You're adding it to the list belonging to `Fundacion`. But every time `VistaPrincipalController` is created it gets a reference to a **new** list, one not backed by `Fundacion`'s list.

Comment: Thank you, you were right, a create a new list everytime the main controller initialize, I made a getter to the class Fundacion to get the list and then work with the methods I already have and now it works fine!!!